# Decorator vs Chain of Responsibility DP

Tags: design-patterns, decorator, chain-of-responsibility

Is there an example of a system which uses Decorator design pattern that isn't suitable for Chain of Responsibility design pattern?

Note: I'm not searching for an explanation, I need an example to my specific problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the CoR and the Decorator? Why is CoR a behavioral pattern? Why is Decorator a structural pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673275/what-is-the-difference-between-the-cor-and-the-decorator-why-is-cor-a-behaviora)

Comment: No it doesn't, I didn't ask for an explanation! I asked for an example for my specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fair, in practical use these two patterns are so closely related as to be almost indistinguishable. I usually just refer to classes that wrap other classes of the same type as *Decorators*. If we have to stick by the definitions in the book, though, they are different.

Decorators do some stuff before and after, while Chain of Responsibility *either* does something *or* calls the next element in the chain.

I recently used this small Decorator graph in a code base:

```
new EmailingReservationsRepository(
    postOffice,
    new LoggingReservationsRepository(
        logger,
        new SqlReservationsRepository(connStr)))
```

`EmailingReservationsRepository`, `LoggingReservationsRepository`, and `SqlReservationsRepository` all implement the same interface:

```
public interface IReservationsRepository
{
    Task Create(int restaurantId, Reservation reservation);

    Task<IReadOnlyCollection<Reservation>> ReadReservations(
        int restaurantId, DateTime min, DateTime max);

    Task<Reservation?> ReadReservation(int restaurantId, Guid id);

    Task Update(int restaurantId, Reservation reservation);

    Task Delete(int restaurantId, Guid id);
}
```

When a client calls, say, `Create`, `EmailingReservationsRepository` first does this:

```
public async Task Create(int restaurantId, Reservation reservation)
{
    await Inner.Create(restaurantId, reservation);
    await PostOffice.EmailReservationCreated(restaurantId, reservation);
}
```

The `Inner` instance is, in this case, the `LoggingReservationsRepository` object, which does this:

```
public async Task Create(int restaurantId, Reservation reservation)
{
    Logger.LogInformation(
        "{method}(restaurantId: {restaurantId}, reservation: {reservation})",
        nameof(Create),
        restaurantId,
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(reservation.ToDto()));
    await Inner.Create(restaurantId, reservation);
}
```

and finally `SqlReservationsRepository` saves the `reservation` in a relational database.

You can't use Chain of Responsibility for this, because each element in the chain would have to *either* handle the method call *or* pass it on. It can't do both; if it does, it's no longer Chain of Responsibility.

In practice, the distinction between these two patterns is blurred to the extent that I don't really care. I just call most of these things *Decorators* and move on.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Are EmailingReservationsRepository, LoggingReservationsRepository, and SqlReservationsRepository ConcreteComponents or ConcreteDecorators?